# Error in SQL Syntax.....to use near '7)' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql

You have an error in your SQL syntax;

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '7)' at line 1

i am getting above error in following code so please suggest me any appropriate way to run this code..
Thanks in advance...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{   
    String str1=(String)ae.getActionCommand();
    Object source = ae.getSource();
    if(source==home)
    {
        this.dispose();
        home t=new home();
        t.nn("","","","");
    }
    if(source==sh)
    {
        for(p=0;p<12;p++)
        {
            if(mo[p]==dob2.getSelectedItem())
            mo1=p+1;
            if(mo[p]==add2.getSelectedItem())
            mo2=p+1;
        }
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/billing", "root", "");
            Statement stm = c.createStatement();
            t=0;in=0;
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from bill where (to_char(day,'mm') between "+mo1+" and "+mo2+")and(to_char(day,'dd') between "+dob1.getSelectedItem()+"and "+add1.getSelectedItem()+")");
            while(rs.next())
            {   
                t=1;    

                it[in]=rs.getInt("itid");
                ct[in++]=rs.getInt("count");
            }
            if(t==0)
            {
                jp.showMessageDialog(this,"Sorry, No Such Record exisits","INFORMATION",jp.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                t=0;
            }
                c.close();
            stm.close();
    }
```

Comment: Patil instead of executing your query, print your query & execute it in mysql & then check the error

Comment: `to_char()` is a MySQL function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spacing issue on your last "and[...]". Should be " and[...]"

Also, and I may be wrong here, but aren't you confusing Oracle's to_char() and MySQL's date_format() functions?

In Oracle it would be `to_char(day,'mm')` in MySQL it should be `date_format(day,'%m')`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(SYSDATE(), '%m');
Result: 10
```

http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql/to_char_datetime

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty much sure it's a spacing issue. Modify your query like

```
"select * 
from bill 
where to_char(day,'mm') between " + mo1 +" and " + mo2+ " and to_char(day,'dd') between " +dob1.getSelectedItem()+ " and   "+add1.getSelectedItem()+"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use prepared statment instead of statement. This would avoid space issues, quotes issues etc. Moreover you it would prevent you from SQL injection vulnerability.

Issue is space between the parameters in your sql statement as below:

```
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from bill where (to_char(day,'mm') between "+mo1+" and "+mo2+")and(to_char(day,'dd') between "+dob1.getSelectedItem()+"and "+add1.getSelectedItem()+")")
```

It should be

```
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from bill where (to_char(day,'mm') between "+mo1+" and "+mo2+")and(to_char(day,'dd') between "+dob1.getSelectedItem()+" and "+add1.getSelectedItem()+")")
```

Comment: solved this error but after that getting another error i.e. FUNCTION billing.to_char does not exist